# Infinite loop when starting WSO2 5.10 on windows

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Fresh installed WSO2 5.10 using windows installer, and when browsing user-portal i got an infinite loop
on this url, with code and session_state refreshed

https://localhost:9443/user-portal/login?code=f7c96e34-f5d6-379f-89c7-d15274ba5332&session_state=98e9dd8d74663c6fb68fe49ad6e6cae19c9b10610a32a2aac1dcf397d1a6909e.0LckwO0Ea8fzcXJYSjRtMQ

Anybody experienced the same ?

Comment: I just installed fresh 5.10.0 version using the windows installer, and worked on mine. I'm using windows 10. Can you share the console.log ?

Comment: found this TID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2020-03-30 12:45:55,173] [0cfb7cf7-074e-4931-a1f6-04b9822d4351] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService} - Error while evaluating client authenticator : MutualTLSClientAuthenticator ...
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService.lambda$executeClientAuthenticators$0(OAuthClientAuthnService.java:149)

Comment: Have you updated the "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" section in the User Portal service provider? or is it set to default?

Comment: I did several fresh setup. on centos, i deployed sudo rpm -ivh wso2is-linux-installer-x64-5.10.0.rpm. then launch sudo wso2-xxxx, then when i launch the user-portal i got his infinte loop after login with admin/admin. So i did not change anything

Comment: it was working fine on 5.9 but not with the last version 5.10.0.

Comment: You can experience here with admin/admin on https://wso2-ciam.phishlab.site:9443/user-portal

Comment: I tried the above URL and it worked fine for me, with any loops in the login.

Comment: Issue on chrome Version 80.0.3987.162 (Build officiel) (64 bits) Windows 10 and on Firefox i get a logout after 30 second. So something strange cannot explain